# KendoUI Grid Server Side Sort/Filter not applying to the SQL Query

Tags: php, json, kendo-ui

I'm running into a Problem that my grid isn't Sorting/Filtering as expected. I always get all results back from the database.

Here is my JS:

```
<script>
'use strict';
(function($, kendo) {
   $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url:"http://server01/read.php",
                    type: "POST"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "data",
                total: "total",
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        tID: { type: "number" },
                        tTitle: { type: "string" },
                        oDate: { type: "date" },
                        eDate: { type: "date" },
                        cDate: { type: "date" },
                        tKeywords: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 2,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true
        },
        height: 430,
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [{
                field:"tID",
                title:"TicketID",
                width:"60px",
                filterable: false
            },{
                field: "tTitle",
                title: "Ticket Bezeichnung"
            }, {
                field: "oDate",
                title: "Ticket eröffnet",
                format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
                width: "160px"
            }, {
                field: "eDate",
                title: "Ticket escaliert",
                format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
                width: "160px"
            }, {
                field: "cDate",
                title: "Ticket geschlossen",
                format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
                width: "160px"

            }, {
                field: "tKeywords",
                title: "keywords"
            }
        ]
    });
})(jQuery, kendo);
```

On the Server side it looks like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'classes/classes.php';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $request = json_encode($_POST);
    $result = new DataSourceResult('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jarvis','root','',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
    echo json_encode($result->read('jar_ticketing_index', array('tID', 'tTitle', 'tDesc', 'oDate', 'eDate', 'cDate','tKeywords'), $request));
}else{
    echo "Opps...";
}
```

For applying the filters to the Query I'm using the dataSourceResult class:

```
class DataSourceResult {
    private $db;

    private $stringOperators = array(
        'eq' => 'LIKE',
        'neq' => 'NOT LIKE',
        'doesnotcontain' => 'NOT LIKE',
        'contains' => 'LIKE',
        'startswith' => 'LIKE',
        'endswith' => 'LIKE'
    );

    private $operators = array(
        'eq' => '=',
        'gt' => '>',
        'gte' => '>=',
        'lt' => '<',
        'lte' => '<=',
        'neq' => '!='
    );

    private $aggregateFunctions = array(
        'average' => 'AVG',
        'min' => 'MIN',
        'max' => 'MAX',
        'count' => 'COUNT',
        'sum' => 'SUM'
    );

    function __construct($dsn, $username=null, $password=null, $driver_options=null) {
        $this->db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $driver_options);

    }

    private function total($tableName, $properties, $request) {
        if (isset($request->filter)) {
            $where = $this->filter($properties, $request->filter);
            $statement = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tableName $where");
            $this->bindFilterValues($statement, $request->filter);
        } else {
            $statement = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tableName");
        }

        $statement->execute();

        $total = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        return (int)($total[0]);
    }

    private function page() {
        return ' LIMIT :skip,:take';
    }

    private function group($data, $groups, $table, $request, $properties) {
        if (count($data) > 0) {
            return $this->groupBy($data, $groups, $table, $request, $properties);
        }
        return array();
    }

    private function mergeSortDescriptors($request) {
        $sort = isset($request->sort) && count($request->sort) ? $request->sort : array();
        $groups = isset($request->group) && count($request->group) ? $request->group : array();

        return array_merge($sort, $groups);
    }

    private function groupBy($data, $groups, $table, $request, $properties) {
        if (count($groups) > 0) {
            $field = $groups[0]->field;
            $count = count($data);
            $result = array();
            $value = $data[0][$field];
            $aggregates = isset($groups[0]->aggregates) ? $groups[0]->aggregates : array();

            $hasSubgroups = count($groups) > 1;
            $groupItem = $this->createGroup($field, $value, $hasSubgroups, $aggregates, $table, $request, $properties);

            for ($index = 0; $index < $count; $index++) {
                $item = $data[$index];
                if ($item[$field] != $value) {
                    if (count($groups) > 1) {
                        $groupItem["items"] = $this->groupBy($groupItem["items"], array_slice($groups, 1), $table, $request, $properties);
                    }

                    $result[] = $groupItem;

                    $groupItem = $this->createGroup($field, $data[$index][$field], $hasSubgroups, $aggregates, $table, $request, $properties);
                    $value = $item[$field];
                }
                $groupItem["items"][] = $item;
            }

            if (count($groups) > 1) {
                $groupItem["items"] = $this->groupBy($groupItem["items"], array_slice($groups, 1), $table, $request, $properties);
            }

            $result[] = $groupItem;

            return $result;
        }
        return array();
    }

    private function addFilterToRequest($field, $value, $request) {
        $filter = (object)array(
            'logic' => 'and',
            'filters' => array(
                (object)array(
                    'field' => $field,
                    'operator' => 'eq',
                    'value' => $value
                ))
            );

        if (isset($request->filter)) {
            $filter->filters[] = $request->filter;
        }

        return (object) array('filter' => $filter);
    }

    private function addFieldToProperties($field, $properties) {
        if (!in_array($field, $properties)) {
            $properties[] = $field;
        }
        return $properties;
    }

    private function createGroup($field, $value, $hasSubgroups, $aggregates, $table, $request, $properties) {
        if (count($aggregates) > 0) {
            $request = $this->addFilterToRequest($field, $value, $request);
            $properties = $this->addFieldToProperties($field, $properties);
        }

        $groupItem = array(
            'field' => $field,
            'aggregates' => $this->calculateAggregates($table, $aggregates, $request, $properties),
            'hasSubgroups' => $hasSubgroups,
            'value' => $value,
            'items' => array()
        );

        return $groupItem;
    }

    private function calculateAggregates($table, $aggregates, $request, $properties) {
        $count = count($aggregates);

        if (count($aggregates) > 0) {
            $functions = array();

            for ($index = 0; $index < $count; $index++) {
                $aggregate = $aggregates[$index];
                $name = $this->aggregateFunctions[$aggregate->aggregate];
                $functions[] = $name.'('.$aggregate->field.') as '.$aggregate->field.'_'.$aggregate->aggregate;
            }

            $sql = sprintf('SELECT %s FROM %s', implode(', ', $functions), $table);

            if (isset($request->filter)) {
                $sql .= $this->filter($properties, $request->filter);
            }

            $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);

            if (isset($request->filter)) {
                $this->bindFilterValues($statement, $request->filter);
            }

            $statement->execute();

            $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            return $this->convertAggregateResult($result[0]);
        }
        return (object)array();
    }

    private function convertAggregateResult($properties) {
        $result = array();

        foreach($properties as $property => $value) {
            $item = array();
            $split = explode('_', $property);
            $field = $split[0];
            $function = $split[1];
            if (array_key_exists($field, $result)) {
                $result[$field][$function] = $value;
            } else {
                $result[$field] = array($function => $value);
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    private function sort($properties, $sort) {
        $count = count($sort);

        $sql = '';

        if ($count > 0) {
            $sql = ' ORDER BY ';

            $order = array();

            for ($index = 0; $index < $count; $index ++) {
                $field = $sort[$index]->field;

                if (in_array($field, $properties)) {
                    $dir = 'ASC';

                    if ($sort[$index]->dir == 'desc') {
                        $dir = 'DESC';
                    }

                    $order[] = "$field $dir";
                }

            }

            $sql .= implode(',', $order);
        }

        return $sql;
    }

    private function where($properties, $filter, $all) {
        if (isset($filter->filters)) {
            $logic = ' AND ';

            if ($filter->logic == 'or') {
                $logic = ' OR ';
            }

            $filters = $filter->filters;

            $where = array();

            for ($index = 0; $index < count($filters); $index++) {
                $where[] = $this->where($properties, $filters[$index], $all);
            }

            $where = implode($logic, $where);

            return "($where)";
        }

        $field = $filter->field;

        if (in_array($field, $properties)) {
            $index = array_search($filter, $all);

            $value = ":filter$index";

            if ($this->isDate($filter->value)) {
                $field = "date($field)";
                $value = "date($value)";
            }

            if ($this->isString($filter->value)) {
                $operator = $this->stringOperators[$filter->operator];
            } else {
                $operator = $this->operators[$filter->operator];
            }

            return "$field $operator $value";
        }
    }

    private function flatten(&$all, $filter) {
        if (isset($filter->filters)) {
            $filters = $filter->filters;

            for ($index = 0; $index < count($filters); $index++) {
                $this->flatten($all, $filters[$index]);
            }
        } else {
            $all[] = $filter;
        }
    }

    private function filter($properties, $filter) {
        $all = array();

        $this->flatten($all, $filter);

        $where = $this->where($properties, $filter, $all);

        return " WHERE $where";
    }

    private function isDate($value) {
        $result = date_parse($value);
        return $result["error_count"] < 1;
    }

    private function isString($value) {
        return !is_bool($value) && !is_numeric($value) && !$this->isDate($value);
    }

    private function bindFilterValues($statement, $filter) {
        $filters = array();
        $this->flatten($filters, $filter);

        for ($index = 0; $index < count($filters); $index++) {
            $value = $filters[$index]->value;
            $operator = $filters[$index]->operator;
            $date = date_parse($value);

            if ($operator == 'contains' || $operator == 'doesnotcontain') {
                $value = "%$value%";
            } else if ($operator == 'startswith') {
                $value = "$value%";
            } else if ($operator == 'endswith') {
                $value = "%$value";
            }

            $statement->bindValue(":filter$index", $value);
        }
    }

    public function create($table, $properties, $models, $key) {
        $result = array();
        $data = array();

        if (!is_array($models)) {
            $models = array($models);
        }

        $errors = array();

        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $columns = array();
            $values = array();
            $input_parameters = array();

            foreach ($properties as $property) {
                if ($property != $key) {
                    $columns[] = $property;
                    $values[] = '?';
                    $input_parameters[] = $model->$property;
                }
            }

            $columns = implode(', ', $columns);
            $values = implode(', ', $values);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($values)";

            $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);

            $statement->execute($input_parameters);

            $status = $statement->errorInfo();

            if ($status[1] > 0) {
                $errors[] = $status[2];
            } else {
                $model->$key = $this->db->lastInsertId();
                $data[] = $model;
            }
        }

        if (count($errors) > 0) {
            $result['errors'] = $errors;
        } else {
            $result['data'] = $data;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function destroy($table, $models, $key) {
        $result = array();

        if (!is_array($models)) {
            $models = array($models);
        }

        $errors = array();

        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE $key=?";

            $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);

            $statement->execute(array($model->$key));

            $status = $statement->errorInfo();

            if ($status[1] > 0) {
                $errors[] = $status[2];
            }
        }

        if (count($errors) > 0) {
            $result['errors'] = $errors;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function update($table, $properties, $models, $key) {
        $result = array();

        if (in_array($key, $properties)) {

            if (!is_array($models)) {
                $models = array($models);
            }

            $errors = array();

            foreach ($models as $model) {
                $set = array();

                $input_parameters = array();

                foreach ($properties as $property) {
                    if ($property != $key) {
                        $set[] = "$property=?";
                        $input_parameters[] = $model->$property;
                    }
                }

                $input_parameters[] = $model->$key;

                $set = implode(', ', $set);

                $sql = "UPDATE $table SET $set WHERE $key=?";

                $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);

                $statement->execute($input_parameters);

                $status = $statement->errorInfo();

                if ($status[1] > 0) {
                    $errors[] = $status[2];
                }
            }

            if (count($errors) > 0) {
                $result['errors'] = $errors;
            }
        }

        if (count($result) == 0) {
            $result = "";
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function read($table, $properties, $request = null) {
        $result = array();

        $result['total'] = $this->total($table, $properties, $request);

        $sql = sprintf('SELECT %s FROM %s', implode(', ', $properties), $table);

        if (isset($request->filter)) {
            $sql .= $this->filter($properties, $request->filter);
        }

        $sort = $this->mergeSortDescriptors($request);

        if (count($sort) > 0) {
            $sql .= $this->sort($properties, $sort);
        }

        if (isset($request->skip) && isset($request->take)) {
            $sql .= $this->page();
        }

        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        if (isset($request->filter)) {
            $this->bindFilterValues($statement, $request->filter);
        }

        if (isset($request->skip) && isset($request->take)) {
            $statement->bindValue(':skip', (int)$request->skip, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $statement->bindValue(':take', (int)$request->take, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }

        $statement->execute();

        $data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (isset($request->group) && count($request->group) > 0) {
            $data = $this->group($data, $request->group, $table, $request, $properties);
            $result['groups'] = $data;
        } else {
            $result['data'] = $data;
        }

        if (isset($request->aggregate)) {
            $result["aggregates"] = $this->calculateAggregates($table, $request->aggregate, $request, $properties);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

I always get all of the records back from the database. It looks like my DataSourceResult Object isn't getting the filter variables the right way. But I don't see any error at all.

Could you give me a hint?

Comment: So how are you applying the filter to the grid?Can you post the code for applying filter?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? When I click on the title bar I see the ajax request fired in FireBug. And also the JSON which is returned, but its not in the expected new order. I just get all the records back as I got them in the grid allready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke I pointed it out. The Filter I got by POST need to be passed as an object to the dataSourceResult Class.

$object = json_decode(json_encode($_POST), FALSE);

Now its working like a charm!

Comment: I'm having similar problems. My setup is essentially the same as yours. The DataSourceResult class is returning the correct data, and filtering using any of the regular operators is working. However, filtering with the stringoperators doesn't work.

Comment: Oops... sorted it: I wasn't stringifying the read parameters using ParameterMap. It works perfectly now.